# What determines the data type of a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am working using Python (Windows 64 bit). I wrote the following script:

```
y = np.array[(4,5,6)]
z = np.array([y, y**2])
z.dtype
```

While I run the above code it returned the type 'int32', however the exact same code gave a value of 'int64' in Christopher Brooks Coursera course [*Introduction to Data Science in Python*](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-data-analysis).

Why is this the case?

Comment: Probably the *word length* of the machine, as well as the range of the data elements.

Answer (score 3):

[NumPy defaults to converting Python ints to `numpy.int_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.types.html), a dtype that corresponds to C `long`. On Windows, C `long` is 32-bit even on a 64-bit machine. On Linux, C `long` would be 64-bit, so you'd get `np.int64`.